# Determine the constants C and K so that ${Ce^{iK\pi}}/{2e^{i\pi/4}} = 1+i$

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

Determine the constants C and K so that
$$
\frac{Ce^{iK\pi}}{2e^{i\pi/4}} = 1+i
$$

Pretty sure you need to use De Moivres formula and Eulers formula (complex numbers in notation)
Need help!!

Comment: Are we told that $C$ and $K$ are necessarily real numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Simplify the left side and write the right side in polar form to get
$$
\frac{C}{2}e^{i \pi [K - 1/4]} = \sqrt{2} e^{i \pi/4}.
$$